# Twitter oauth without server, or server in different domain

Tags: javascript, rest, twitter, oauth, twitter-rest-api

I have a site on angular (e.g: app-client.com), where every piece of data comes from another REST API site (e.g: app-api.com).

The app-client.com is only a bunch of html, css, and javascript files, and no server-side scripts (None of these: PHP, ASPX, python, node.js). How can I add a feature to use twitter API in behalf of my user?

I know some oauth providers have 'implicit grant oauth', does twitter has it?

Is there any way (even hack-ish is welcome) how to use oauth or, at minimum, get user access-token in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is accessing Twitter API from your `app-api.com`, if possible. Twitter don't have any client side API yet, because of oAuth scheme that require `consumer-secret` etc that must be securely store in server side.

Comment: Thanks. I may have to find other ways.